# DatGridView Header Cell's Background Color

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, paint

I want to Get the DataGridView Header Cell's Background color, I have done a trick but its giving me empty and RGB = 0,0,0

I have try this code:

```
 Color cl = dataGridView1.Columns["<Column>"].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor; //<AnyColumn>
```

I have to repaint Header Cell's Background of the same color as it has before repainting with size modifications .

Kindly Suggest a Solution, I have searched a lot but no useful help

Comment: It seems you are using `CssClass` in your `GridView` markup. I think if you use `HeaderCell.Style.BackColor` in your markup, you can get it back.

Comment: My Question is regarding >net C#,VB.Net WinForms Related, So I need solution for that

Comment: @Iqbal, in Windows form, we dont have aspx

Comment: @Arshad Sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some efforts, I finally write down code with some suggestions
Its a Generic Code that can be call at any Grid's Paint Method of C# WinForm, pass it the Grid,The Columns's names, and the paint Graphics object

I have added a fill rectangle of size 4, that starts from the previous column's Right-2 to Next Column's Left+2 , So it hides the Vertical Bar

```
Public Sub VerticalBarHide(ByVal grd As KryptonExtendedGrid, ByVal colname As String(), ByVal e As System.Drawing.Graphics)
    Dim rectHeader As Rectangle
    grd.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
    Dim bgColor As Color
    bgColor = grd.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor
    For Each name As String In colname
        rectHeader = grd.GetCellDisplayRectangle(grd.Columns(name).Index, -1, True)
        rectHeader.X = rectHeader.X + rectHeader.Width - 2
        rectHeader.Y += 1
        rectHeader.Width = 2 * 2
        rectHeader.Height -= 2
        e.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(bgColor), rectHeader)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

The `DataGridView` uses style inheritance, so unless an individual header cell differs from the default, its `BackColor` will be set to `Color.Empty`.

Try the `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor` property instead.

Note that when `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` is set to true (the default), the value will be ignored and the headers will be drawn using a visual style renderer instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this working well. You need to set `EnableHeadersVisualStyles=fasle;`
I have tested in both the ways:

```
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;

DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn = dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"];
dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;

Color cl = dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor;
//or   
Color cl2 = dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor;
```

Comment: Its fine, when we "dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;" but problem was there , it was giving value as 0,0,0,0 means empty

Comment: @Bradley Smith : So I have used this property after disabling its Visual-Style property "Color cl = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;" and I have successfully achieved